# Django sending data to front-end. 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

I have these methods:

```
def get_all_from_database():
    urls = Url.objects.all()
    ips = Ip.objects.all()
    context = {
        'urls': serializers.serialize('json', urls),
        'ip': serializers.serialize('json', ips)
    }
    return context
```

and the method that sends data to using ajax:

```
def send_results(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        address = request.POST.get('url')
    process_data(address, email_to, email_from)
    context = get_all_from_database()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type='application/json')
```

But this raises error : INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 500 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'.
Wheres the mistake, and how to correct it ?

Answer (score 2):

You cant use `serializers.serialize` method with **dict list** that you got from `values` call:

```
urls = Url.objects.all().values('address', 'cnt')
```

Use default queryset:

```
urls = Url.objects.all()
ips = Ip.objects.all()
```

Comment: I corrected that, but now it raises : '*some data* is not JSON serializable'

Answer (score 1):

```
urls = Url.objects.all().values('address', 'cnt')
ips = Ip.objects.all().values('address', 'cnt')
```

The above lines returns `dict` objects, try:

```
urls = Url.objects.all().values('address', 'cnt').values_list()
ips = Ip.objects.all().values('address', 'cnt').values_list()
```

Then you will have `urls` as a list containing the tuples:

```
[(address_1, cnt_1), (address_2, cnt_2), ...]
```

see: [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)

Answer (score 1):

In you example `context['urls']` value already in `json` format, and you cant use `json.dumps()` for json data.
You can use this example:

```
json.dumps({
    'urls': Urls.objects.all().values_list('address', 'cnt'),
    'ips': Ip.objects.all().values_list('address', 'cnt')
}), 'json')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be :

```
   res=json.dumps({
        'urls': list(Urls.objects.all().values_list('address', 'cnt')),
        'ips': list(Ip.objects.all().values_list('address', 'cnt'))
    }), 'json')
    return HttpResponse(res,content_type="application/json")
```